# calculus, change in population growth

Tags: calculus

Population  size    $p(t)$ of Barbuda changes   over    time    at  the rate $p'(t)$ given   by  the expression $$p'(t)=10\,(6t + e^{-t})\,(2t+1)$$

where $t$ denotes    time in years. What will be the change  of  Barbuda population  in  $10$  years?

Comment: The problem is, I believe, asking for the change in the population...thus they want $p(10)-p(0)$.  You will have to integrate your expression for $p'(t)$.

Comment: Do you know how to solve differential equations?

Answer (score 1):

We are given that $\frac{dp}{dt} = 10(6t+e^{-t})(2t+1)$ which expands to $$\frac{dp}{dt} = 120t^2+60t+20te^{-t}+10e^{-t}$$.

This is a separable differential equation, so (pretending to) multiply by $dt$ and then taking the integral we get $$\int dp = \int120t^2dt+\int60tdt+\int20te^{-t}dt+\int10e^{-t}dt$$ which gives $$p=40t^3+30t^2+10e^{-t}+20\int te^{-t}dt$$

To solve the integral $\int te^{-t}dt$, perform integration by parts with $u=t \implies \frac{du}{dt} = 1$ and $\frac{dv}{dt}=e^{-t} \implies v=-e^{-t}$, which yields $$\int te^{-t}dt=-te^{-t}-\int -e^{-t}dt = -te^{-t}-e^{-t} + C= -e^{-t}(t+1) + C$$.

Substituting back into the original integral: $p(t)=40t^3+30t^2+10e^{-t}-20e^{-t}(t+1) + C$.

You now want $p(10) - p(0)$, to find which you can simply substitute in $10$ and $0$ into the above equation - the arbitrary constant will cancel out.